# Count a document property in a projection using MongoDB and Javascript

Tags: mongodb

I've this document:

```
{
  _id: XXXX,
  id: 1,
  name: 'User1'
  notifications: [{
    id: 1,
    read: false
 }, {
    id: 2,
    read: false
 }, {
    id: 3,
    read: false
 }, {
    id: 4,
    read: true
 }, {
    id: 5,
    read: true
 }]
}
```

I want to get this result without doing a double query: (creating a property at the end counting all `notifications` that aren't read yet)

```
   {
      id: 1,
      name: 'User1'
      notifications: [{
        id: 1,
        seen: false
     }, {
        id: 2,
        seen: false
     }, {
        id: 3,
        seen: false
     }, {
        id: 4,
        seen: true
     }, {
        id: 5,
        seen: true
     }],
     notRead: 3
    }
```

My current code:

```
const user = await db.collection('users').findOne({id: 1}, {projection: {_id: 0, id: 1, name: 1, notifications: {$slice: 20}, notRead: {
  notifications: {
    $count: {
      $eq: ['$notifications.read', false]
    }
  }
}}})
```

Is it possible? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$filter` to iterate the loop of `notifications` and filter your condition and use `$size` to get total element from filtered result

```
const user = await db.collection('users').findOne(
  { id: 1 }, 
  { 
    _id: 0, 
    id: 1, name: 1, 
    notifications: { $slice: 20 }, 
    notRead: {
      $size: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$notifications",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.read", false] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mtp7_hI-k45)

Comment: If we improve this case changing property read to an array of strings (array of usersId), how could I solve it? I've test in in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KHILlGL9KE4) but i get 5 notRead instead of 2. Thank you very much, turivishal

Comment: just swap your match in $in, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VMH9LP9TMjX)

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, if we improve it and want to project the data filtered of a subdocument, how could I achieve it? [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gp6LkJl-Z97)

Comment: not getting you exactly, it is ok if you ask new question with more details.

Comment: I created a new question here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887704/count-a-subdocument-property-in-a-projection-using-mongodb-and-javascript)

Comment: I whish you could help me with this new question that improves this last one.. [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67935366/sum-of-subdocument-and-document-properties-conditionally-in-mongodb)