# Sum of subdocument and document properties conditionally in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get a sum of all room notifications + subroom notifications (this one's only if If there is a mutual element between subRoom Roles and Users[x].Roles) and getting aswell a list of all subRooms without taking into account if user has matching roles or not.

*Roles allow Users to access or not to SubRooms

**Documents:**

```
     [
          {
            _id: 1,
            id: 1,
            room: "Room1",
            notifications: [
              {
                id: 1,
                read: []
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                read: []
              },
              {
                id: 3,
                read: ["User1"]
              }
            ],
            users: [{
              userId: "User1",
              roles: ["A", "D"]
            },{
              userId: "User2",
              roles: ["B", "C", "D"]
            }],
            subRooms: [
              {
                id: "SubRoom1",
                roles: ["A", "B", "C"]
                notifications: [
                  {
                    id: 1,
                    read: []
                  },
                  {
                    id: 2,
                    read: ["User2"]
                  },
                  {
                    id: 3,
                    read: ["User1", "User2"]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                id: "SubRoom2",
                roles: ["C"]
                notifications: [
                  {
                    id: 1,
                    read: []
                  },
                  {
                    id: 2,
                    read: []
                  },
                  {
                    id: 3,
                    read: ["User2"]
                  }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
For User1 Search:

[ 
  {
    _id: 1,
    id: 1,
    room: "Room1",
    subRooms: ["SubRoom1", "SubRoom2"] // All subRooms without taking into account if user has matching roles or not
    totalNotReadNotifications: 4 // 2 notifications of SubRoom1 + 2 notifications of Room
  }
]
```

For User 2 Search:

```
[ 
  {
    _id: 1,
    id: 1,
    room: "Room1",
    subRooms: ["SubRoom1", "SubRoom2"] // All subRooms without taking into account if user has matching roles or not
    totalNotReadNotifications: 6 // 1 notification of SubRoom 1 + 2 notifications of SubRoom2 + 3 notifications of Room
  }
]
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: why its double the count in result?

Comment: Because in the first result case, you're finding all notifications that haven't been seen by "User1". It's a sum of the room notifications and all subrooms notifications. In second result case you're counting notifications of "User2". I wrote two queries examples to see the difference of "totalNotReadNotifications" count parameter.

Comment: Room has two subRooms. Each room has notifications and each subroom has notifications as well. I want to count the sum of all notifications parameter where user queried is not in "Read" array

Comment: okay, it will search one user at a time?

Comment: yes, only one user at a time, but instead of searching just one room, it will search for multiple rooms through an array of rooms using --> db.col.find("id": {$in: arrayOfRooms}). I just wrote one room doc to show the example

Comment: its totally lengthy process for this operation, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JfPSQXuQfQA)

Comment: Thank you very much, if you want, write it as an answer and I'll upvote and confirm it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields
- get main total unread notifications to count by `$filter` and `$size` operators
- get filtered `subRoom` by $let and `$filter` operators
- `$addFields` to get total unread notifications from filtered `subRoom` and sum with main notifications count
- `$unset` to remove `subRoom` field its not needed

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      room: 1,
      subRooms: "$subRoom.id",
      totalNotReadNotifications: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$notifications",
            cond: { $not: { $in: ["User1", "$$this.read"] } }
          }
        }
      },
      subRoom: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            user: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$users",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this.userId", "User1"] }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$subRoom",
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$$this.roles",
                      cond: { $in: ["$$this", "$$user.roles"] }
                    }
                  },
                  []
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalNotReadNotifications: {
        $add: [
          "$totalNotReadNotifications",
          {
            $sum: {
              $map: {
                input: "$subRoom",
                in: {
                  $size: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$$this.notifications",
                      cond: { $not: { $in: ["User1", "$$this.read"] } }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "subRoom" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JfPSQXuQfQA)